# g++: "command not found" after declaring variables in Bash

Tags: shell, g++

The `g++` command doesn't work after declaring a variable before the `g++` command.

For example, the following works:

```
echo "Train LINE starts"
g++ -lm -pthread -Ofast -march=native -Wall -funroll-loops -ffast-math -Wno-unused-result line.cpp -o line -lgsl -lm -lgslcblas
```

But this does *not*:

```
PATH="foo path"
echo "Train LINE starts"
g++ -lm -pthread -Ofast -march=native -Wall -funroll-loops -ffast-math -Wno-unused-result line.cpp -o line -lgsl -lm -lgslcblas
```

Instead, I get an error: **`g++: command not found`**. Is it the correct way of declaring variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PATH` environment variable consists of a colon-delimited list of directories. The shell searches for executable files in these directories in response to commands issued by a user.

For example, if `g++` executable is located in `/usr/bin` directory, then you can implicitly call `/usr/bin/g++` only if `PATH` contains `/usr/bin`:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin
```

If you want to add a search path, you should append it to the existing value of the variable:

```
PATH="$PATH:/new/search/path"
```

Answer (score 2):

The `PATH` variable holds the path to your programs witch the shell is looking for. So if you change that, the shell doesn't find the program. You can add an folder by using

```
PATH=/usr/local/progdir:$PATH
export PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example you redefine `PATH` which is used to lookup the directory where  `g++` lives.  Use a different variable name.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to append a new path in PATH variable, use this:

```
PATH=$PATH:foopath
```

instead of:

```
PATH="foo path"
```

If you are using PATH as variable for anything else, use another name.